# CentOS Epel Error

Tags: xml, git, centos, epel

I am having problem with `yum install <...>` command. I am using CentOS 6.6. My epel.repo scripts are as follow ->

```
[epel]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch
baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64
#mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6

[epel-debuginfo]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Debug
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/$basearch/debug
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-debug-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1

[epel-source]
name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - $basearch - Source
#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/SRPMS
mirrorlist=https://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/metalink?repo=epel-source-6&arch=$basearch
failovermethod=priority
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-EPEL-6
gpgcheck=1
```

When I am executing `yum install git` command for example, this error returned ->

```
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Update Process
Repository centosplus is listed more than once in the configuration
Repository contrib is listed more than once in the configuration
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * extras: centos.exabytes.com.my
 * updates: centos.exabytes.com.my
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6//repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 404 Not Found"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: EPEL. Please verify its path and try again
```

Looks like the url `http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6//repodata/repomd.xml` is not properly set up thus trigger 404 error not found. And for the second error, I have no idea why. I think it is because the repomd.xml couldn't be retrieved.

The url should be `http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml` as per epel.repo configuration file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to install EPEL again using [those steps](http://itekblog.com/centos-epel/).

Copying it to here:

```
rpm -Uvh http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/i386/epel-release-6-8.noarch.rpm
```

**UPDATE:**

Try to Use this command instead, as it should always install the latest release (didn't tested it).

```
rpm -Uvh http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm
```

Comment: I have remove epel completely and went through fresh installation process as per advice. So, the problem above disappear. However, new error appears. `Error: Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: epel. Please verify its path and try again`. Can advice? BTW I have disable https with http request also in the repo file. Still the same error.

Comment: First, I've updated the url in the answer to install latest epel release. about the new error I don't have a clue.

Comment: http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-6.noarch.rpm -> Forbidden